# Strange prob­lem with seemingly equal strings

Tags: javascript

I know this might look silly, but I still don't know why this happens (for a couple times already.)

```
alert(
"WWVhaCA6RCwgYSBsb3Qgb2YgcGVvcGxlIGRvbid0IGtub3cgdGhhdCB0aGlzIGlzIGVuY29kZWQgOkQ=" == 
"WWVhaCA6RCwgYSBsb3Qgb2YgcGVvcGxlIGRvbid0IGtub3cgdGhhdCB0aGlzIGlzIGVuY29kZWQgOkQ=")​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/b38Cn/

It should return `true` but instead it returns `false`. I looked through each character (in Notepad because it uses a monospace font), and they are exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the lengths? The first is 81 whereas the second is 80 long.

Comment: @Andreas - How did the 81th character `65279` get into the string?

Comment: Copy&Paste, messed up php script, ... There are some options for this problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ElliotBonneville says, there is a hidden unicode character in the text. It is visible by pasting the strings into command prompt:

[image: screenshot]

Notice the `?` at the end of the first string.

Comment: Nice find, didn't think to paste the strings into the command prompt. What made you think of that?

Comment: I did a length compare, noticed the difference and turned to plain-old special-character-intolerant DOS! :)

Answer (score 4):

Strangely enough, when I copy & paste your code to my editor, I end up with this:

> "WWVhaCA6RCwgYSBsb3Qgb2YgcGVvcGxlIGRvbid0IGtub3cgdGhhdCB0aGlzIGlzIGVuY29kZWQgOkQ=**?**"

and the second part:

> "WWVhaCA6RCwgYSBsb3Qgb2YgcGVvcGxlIGRvbid0IGtub3cgdGhhdCB0aGlzIGlzIGVuY29kZWQgOkQ="

Notice the extra "**?**" in the first string? Visually on jsFiddle it does not appear.
I copied your strings and removed the extra **?** and ran it on jsFiddle. It worked fine.

Comment: Ups...sorry. Didn't see Elliot Bonneville and bPratik replies.

Comment: no bother, +1 to get you started on SO!

Answer (score 3):

Did you copy this string from jsFiddle or something? There is a Unicode character that isn't showing up in Notepad or my browser (Chrome, if you're wondering) and is causing the issue. Copying the first string and pasting it into the second one (after confirming that the two *appear* the same) caused the issue to disappear.

I'd paste a link to an updated jsFiddle, but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: You're not allowed to? Is there some policy about that?

Comment: Apparently, yes. It must be because so many people were simply posting links to jsFiddle instead of actual code in their answers. It's new, I haven't seen it before.

Comment: I know people don't like it when you post a question as nothing but a fiddle. But it's not bad to include one if you have an explanation to follow with. In your case, You explain it thoroughly so there should be no harm in adding a fiddle to support the statement. Now, if you just posted a fiddle with no answer then yeah, downvote all day long.

Answer (score 3):

Say hello to the [zero width non breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)!

Your first string includes a `0xfeff` character at the end. This wouldn't show up in most modern editors, which is probably why you didn't even notice it.

> Zero-width non-breaking space (ZWNBSP) is a deprecated use of the Unicode character at code point U+FEFF. Character U+FEFF is intended for use as a Byte Order Mark at the start of a file. However, if encountered elsewhere it should, according to Unicode, be treated as a "zero-width non-breaking space". The deliberate use of U+FEFF for this purpose is now deprecated, with U+2060 word joiner (HTML: ⁠) strongly preferred.

Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space)

When you encounter seemingly identical strings you should break them down using `.charCodeAt()` inside a loop to find any "rogue" characters.